# Div with box-shadow inset appears with black half in safari browser

Tags: css, angular, safari, mobile-safari

I am building a div that has a background that works in all browsers except Safari, in which it appears with a black half.

[image]

The application has been built in Angular and the code is as follows

```
// HTML
<div class="card" [style.backgroundImage]="'url('myBlob/img/' + data.destination.code.toLowerCase() + '.jpg)'" *ngIf="data.price >= 0">
    <p class="city-info">
        <span class="city-name">{{ data.destination.city }}</span>
        <span class="country-name">{{ data.destination.country }}</span>
    </p>
    <p class="city-price">{{ data.price | number:'1.0-0' }}€</p>
</div>

// CSS
background-color: #DDD;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 210px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.25), inset 0px -240px 120px -80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transition: all 0.22s cubic-bezier(.2, .08, .6, .99);
    width: 100%;
```

The images are in jpg format and measure approx 500px-700px

demo
[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rvfgt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rvfgt)

Comment: Can you add any working example on stackblitz etc that will help to find the culprit. Thanks

Comment: Sure, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6rvfgt, I verified thats doesnt work in safari in Iphone 11, I regarding the code I have only removed the background-attach property @KamranKhatti

Comment: Could you provide Safari or iOS version? I checked in OSX Safari Versión 12.1.2 and Iphone 8 Plus with IOS Versión 13.1.3 and it works fine... :S

Comment: @juanjinario may be it is a problem with progressive load with your .jpg. Could you try to change .jpg to .gif and test it?

Comment: Its imposible change the type of the images (are 300 or 400), if I increase the size of the card if it works, it's all very strange. @AlbertoRhuertas. 
The test was carried out on 3 Iphones 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the negative box-shadow inset spread

I solved it by changing the following:

```
box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.25), inset 0px -240px 120px **-80px** rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

for

box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.25), inset 0px -240px 120px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.25), inset 0px -240px 120px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

The effect will not be the same, but Safari doesn't like it